# How to get table data from Wikipedia page?

Tags: json, xml, wikipedia-api

Is there somebody who knows how to use the `Wikipedia API` to get `JSON` or `XML` data out from a table on a specific Wikipedia page?

Is there maybe a different way to do this?

For example from here `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_action_films_of_the_2010s`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `curl` (or use any other method/tool) to retrieve and/or *parse* a Wikipedia-URL via the public API. Here are two examples that should help you:

Retrieval of *List_of_action_films_of_the_2010s:*

- [JSON unparsed](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=List_of_action_films_of_the_2010s&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json) via the `query` action
- [JSON parsed](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=List_of_action_films_of_the_2010s&contentmodel=wikitext&prop=wikitext&format=json) via the `parse` action

Next, you would need to parse for and/or select the sub-elements relevant for your analysis. In this case I would assume: `wikitable` elements.

For reference and a detailed explanation, you can have a look at the general [API page of MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) and at the list of parameters on how to use the API to [parse Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) pages for certain data elements.